# Hiding/showing hint text in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-material

I want to show some hint text below an input **if the input has no errors on $error**. So either show hint text, or show error message if there is an error.

I have tried using combinations of ngShow/Hide and $valid/$invalid but I can't seem to get it to work the way I need it to.

```
<div ng-form="reg.form" name="reg.form" novalidate>
   <md-input-container flex="100">
      <label>{{"views.application.mobile.label" | translate}}</label>
      <input type="tel" ng-model="reg.user.mobile" name="mobile" required
             ng-pattern="/(^04(\s?[0-9]{2}\s?)([0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2})$)/">
      <div ng-show="???" class="hint">e.g. 0400123123</div>
      <div ng-messages="reg.form.mobile.$error">
        <p class="help-block" ng-message="required">{{"views.application.mobile.error.required" | translate}}</p>
        <p class="help-block" ng-message="pattern">{{"views.application.mobile.error.invalid" | translate}}</p>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: `I can't seem to get it to work the way I need it to` ... what is the output that you are getting? Can you create a jsfiddle / plunker and show us what you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `$untouched` in combination with `$error`. `$untouched` will display the hint initially. Validation errors will kick in on blur. From this point on, since the field is "touched", the hint will be displayed unless input is invalid. In your case, something like this should work:

```
<div ng-show="reg.form.mobile.$untouched || (!reg.form.mobile.$error.required && !reg.form.mobile.$error.pattern)"
    class="hint">
    e.g. 0400123123
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this demo it will help you: http://plnkr.co/edit/lbiKfYbkZJWSu5oUmsAe?p=preview

'Error message' will be shown if the field is empty otherwise 'hint message' will be shown. Below is the related HTML & JS code

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="userForm" novalidate>
      <label>
        First Name: <br/>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" required><br />
        <span class="error" ng-show="userForm.firstname.$error.required">Please enter First name<br /></span>
        <span class="hint" ng-show="!userForm.firstname.$error.required">Hint: First name cannot left blank<br /></span><br />
      </label>
      <label>
        Last Name: <br/>
        <input name="lastname" type="text" ng-model="user.lastName" required><br />
        <span class="error" ng-show="userForm.lastname.$error.required">Please enter Last name<br /></span>
        <span class="hint" ng-show="!userForm.lastname.$error.required">Hint: Last name cannot left blank<br /></span><br />
      </label>
      <button ng-click="submitUser()">Submit</button>&nbsp;<button>Cancel</button>
    </form>
    <pre>{{ user|json }}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isSubmitted = false;
  $scope.submitUser = function() {
    $scope.isSubmitted = true;
  };
});
```

Comment: This is close, but I need the hint text to be shown before submit is hit, so it must be shown at all times while there is no error

Comment: @ljenkins, i have updated the above plunker. Hint will be shown if there is no error at all times even before submit is clicked.